# How to make Magento 2 log timestamp follows locale configuration?

Tags: magento2, log, timezone

How can i make exception.log, system.log, , debug.log or any other log inside var/log which is generated from magento 2 follows the configuration timestamp, right now it is showing the utc timezon in the log timezone, how can I set ti to UTC+5 just like my locale configuration in Magento 2 ?

I'm using Magento ver2.4.1